# are spacetime and gravitons one in the same?

Tags: gravity, spacetime

I ask because it seems to me with my admittedly limited knowledge that this doesn't necessarily contradict any widely accepted theory. In fact it would help explain a few incomplete theories. Does anybody have a reason why this couldn't be the case?

A thought I had on this that I find fascinating. The graviton particle being responsible for time, essentially the more gravitons the more time.

Comment: Sorry, but your thought is so imprecise and speculative that, as far as I'm concerned, this question falls into the non-mainstream category, so I'll be voting to close.

Comment: No, they are not. Spacetime is a classical coordinate space and gravitons are quanta of a field the lives in it. It's not a self-consistent model to begin with, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

If we use a quantum field theory to describe gravity then we get a theory with the graviton as a gauge boson propagating in a flat spacetime. We expect this theory to be an [effective theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory) that is useful only where spacetime is not highly curved.

So gravitons are (probably) not a fundamental description of how gravity works, and they do not make up spacetime in any sense. Although there have been lots of suggestions that spacetime is emergent there is no consensus on how this happens.